# T-SQL Select to list all tables in a set database and CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) for each table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to list all tables in a set database, and `CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))` for each table.

I know I can use `sp_tables` to list all tables, but how could I use this with  `CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))` as an extra column on the end?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?  Seems like a lot of potential overhead to track table changes...

Comment: Its not to track table changes, I have the database being replicated but there are difference when there shouldnt be, so want to get CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) of every table in the db on both servers then compare them to see which tables havn't replicated correctly

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, though I have no idea how long it will take on larger databases with a lot of tables:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Tables') is not null
drop table #Tables;

select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as RowNum
        ,t.table_catalog as TableQualifier
        ,t.table_schema as TableOwner
        ,t.table_name as TableName
        ,case t.table_type
            when 'base table'
                then 'table'
            else t.table_type
        end as TableType
        ,null as TableChecksum
into #Tables
from information_schema.tables t
where t.table_type <> 'view';

declare @RowNum int;
declare @TableName nvarchar(100);
declare @TableChecksum bigint;
declare @SQL nvarchar(max);

while (select count(1) from #Tables where TableChecksum is null) > 0
begin
    select top 1 @RowNum = RowNum
                ,@TableName = TableName
                ,@SQL = 'select @TableChecksum = checksum_agg(binary_checksum(*)) from ' + @TableName
    from #Tables
    where TableChecksum is null;

    exec sp_executesql @SQL
                        ,N'@TableChecksum bigint output'
                        ,@TableChecksum output;

    update #Tables
    set TableChecksum = @TableChecksum 
    where RowNum = @RowNum;
end;

select *
from #Tables;

if object_id('tempdb..#Tables') is not null
drop table #Tables;
```

Comment: Weve since decided we wont be doing this kind of task, but thanks for the help!